# Zend Framework2 how to make Concat and Left Join

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db, zend-db-table

Does not work:

```
$sql = new Sql($this->adapter);

$select = $sql->select();
$select->from('request')
           ->columns(array('*', new Expression("CONCAT(up1.value,' ',up2.value) as display_name")))
            ->join(array('up1'=>'user_profile'), "up1.user_id = request.request_user_id AND up1.key = 'user_first_name'", array('up1.value'), 'left')
           ->join(array('up2'=>'user_profile'), "up2.user_id = request.request_user_id AND up2.key = 'user_last_name'", array('up2.value'), 'left')
;

return $select;
```

How to make the right?

Answer (score 0):

You specified fields for both joins:

```
        ->join(array('up1'=>'user_profile'), "up1.user_id = request.request_user_id AND up1.key = 'user_first_name'", array('up1.value'), 'left')
       ->join(array('up2'=>'user_profile'), "up2.user_id = request.request_user_id AND up2.key = 'user_last_name'", array('up2.value'), 'left')
```

When query is converted to actual sql, these fields will be automatically namespaced, so you will get "up1.up1.value" in fields list.

Remove fields references from joins and it should work.

**UPD.** Right, there's more to it. You can't pass 'user_first_name' as a string value to the "on" parameter of join as it will be interpreted as a column name. So you have to pass an expression:

```
    $select = $sql->select();
    $select->from('request')
           ->columns(array('*', new Expression('CONCAT(up1.value,"#",up2.value) as display_name')));

    $expressionString = '? = ? AND ? = ?';
    $types = array(Expression::TYPE_IDENTIFIER, Expression::TYPE_IDENTIFIER, Expression::TYPE_IDENTIFIER, Expression::TYPE_VALUE);

    $parameters = array('request.user_id', 'up1.user_id', 'up1.key', 'first_name');
    $expression1 = new Expression($expressionString, $parameters, $types);

    $parameters = array('request.user_id', 'up2.user_id', 'up2.key', 'last_name');
    $expression2 = new Expression($expressionString, $parameters, $types);

    $select->join(array('up1'=>'user_profile'), $expression1, array('value'), 'left')
           ->join(array('up2'=>'user_profile'), $expression2, array('value'), 'left');
```

Comment: ->columns(array('*', new Expression('CONCAT(up1.value,"#",up2.value) as display_name')))
                ->join(array('up1'=>'user_profile'), 'r.request_user_id = up1.user_id AND up1.key = "user_first_name"', array('value'), 'left')
                ->join(array('up2'=>'user_profile'), 'r.request_user_id = up2.user_id AND up2.key = "user_last_name"', array('value'), 'left') - does not work

Answer (score 0):

Y tri to:

```
$select = $sql->select();
$select->from('request')
           ->columns(array('*', new Expression('CONCAT(up1.value,"#",up2.value) as display_user_name')));

$expressionString = '? = ? AND ? = ?';
$types = array(Expression::TYPE_IDENTIFIER, Expression::TYPE_IDENTIFIER, Expression::TYPE_IDENTIFIER, Expression::TYPE_VALUE);

$parameters1 = array('request.user_id', 'up1.user_id', 'up1.key', 'user_first_name');
$expression1 = new Expression($expressionString, $parameters1, $types);

$parameters2 = array('request.user_id', 'up2.user_id', 'up2.key', 'user_last_name');
$expression2 = new Expression($expressionString, $parameters2, $types);

$select->join(array('up1'=>'user_profile'), $expression1, array('value'), 'left')
           ->join(array('up2'=>'user_profile'), $expression2, array('value'), 'left');
```

***does not work, where the error***